# Evaluate value of JSON Key using NIFI

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I have a scenario where I can have multiple different types of json objects coming into my system. I do not know the object type ahead of time and based upon object type, will route to a different processor in my flow

```
{
  "book": {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "book1"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "video": {
    "id": "3214",
    "name": "video1"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "magazine": {
    "id": "3233",
    "name": "magazine1"
  }
}
```

how can I evaluate if the object is a book, or a video, or a magazine to route to the correct processor

I've tried using evaluatejsonpath using the ~ but it just outputs the entire json object

Current flow :

[image]

Comment: How do you think of routing to a specific processor, currently what tried to handle this or what's your opinion to handle that phase? In short, could you please be more specific in order to be able to get desirable responses  ?

Comment: Do you at least know some of the top level fields? Otherwise, it’s not entirely possible to route the top level

Comment: My goal was to route based on the type of object. So If type == book route to the book processor, etc. The top level fields are consistent so I would know them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extract all top level fields using EvaluateJsonPath processor, set the extracted field values to dynamic properties, and use the properties in RouteOnAttribute processor to route the flow to correct downstream processor.

**EvaluateJsonPath:**

[image]

Please don't forget to set

- 'Destination' to 'flowfile-attribute' and
- 'Return Type' to 'json'

If [EvaluateJsonPath processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) could not find the field or element, then the value of dynamic property will be set to empty string.

All we need to do is to use the dynamic properties in RouteOnAttribute processor.

**RouteOnAttribute:**

Using equals() and not()

[image]

or using isEmpty() and not()

[image]

Please don't forget to set

- 'Routing Strategy' to 'Route to Property Name'.

[Apache NiFi expression language guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)

**Example Flow:**

[image]

I am using PutFile processor as a downstream processor, for an example. It could be any processor.